# Using CompletableFuture with @Async returns an empty response for spring boot API

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

Here is my controller. I used postman to test if it's working but I am getting an empty response. I used `@EnableAsync` in application configuration and `@Async` on the service. If I remove `@Async` on service layer it works but it doesn't run asynchronously.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "search person by passing search criteria event/title/role/host/is_current", response = ElasticSearchResultData.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/async2/searchPerson", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody CompletableFuture<ElasticSearchResultData> searchPersonAsync2(@RequestBody SearchCriteriaTo criteriaForDivNetFolderTo,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    LOGGER.info("searchPerson controller start");
    SearchCriteria searchCriteria = criteriaForDivNetFolderTo.getSearchCriteria();
    if (Util.isNull(searchCriteria)) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("search criteria should not be null.");

    try {
        CompletableFuture<ElasticSearchResultData> searchPerson = cubService.searchPersonAsync2(criteriaForDivNetFolderTo);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        LOGGER.info("search Person "+mapper.writeValueAsString(searchPerson));
        return searchPerson;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception in searchPersonAsync controller "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Service

```
@Async
@Override
public CompletableFuture<ElasticSearchResultData> searchPersonAsync2(SearchCriteriaTo searchCriteriaForDivNetFolderTo) {
   Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   LOGGER.info(":in searchPerson");
   CompletableFuture<ElasticSearchResultData> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
   ElasticSearchResultData searchResultData = null;
   SearchCriteria searchCriteria = searchCriteriaForDivNetFolderTo.getSearchCriteria();
   try {
        LOGGER.info("************ Started searchPerson by criteria ************");
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.append(equilarSearchEngineApiUrl)
        .append(focusCompanySearchUrl)
        .append("/")
        .append("searchPerson")
        .append("?view=").append(VIEW_ALL)
        .append("&isProcessing=true");

        LOGGER.debug("Calling equilar search engine for focused company search, URL : " + url);
        LOGGER.info(searchCriteria.toString());
        String output = null;
        if (redisEnable != null && redisEnable) {
            output = cacheDao.getDataFromRestApi(url.toString(), RequestMethod.POST.name(), searchCriteria);
        } else {
            output = Util.getDataFromRestApi(url.toString(), RequestMethod.POST.name(), searchCriteria);
        }
        if (!Util.isEmptyString(output)) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            searchResultData = objectMapper.readValue(output,
                            objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(ElasticSearchResultData.class));
        }
        List<PersonSearchDetails> newPersonDetails = new ArrayList<PersonSearchDetails>();
        if (!Util.isNull(searchResultData) && !Util.isNullOrEmptyCollection(searchResultData.getPersonDetails())
                && !Util.isNullOrEmptyCollection(searchCriteriaForDivNetFolderTo.getNetworkFoldersData())) {
            for (PersonSearchDetails personDetail : searchResultData.getPersonDetails()) {
                String logoUrl = null;
                if(!Util.isNull(searchCriteria.getTargetFolderId())){
                    List<DiversityNetworkFolderTo> filteredFolderTos = searchCriteriaForDivNetFolderTo
                            .getNetworkFoldersData()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(folder -> folder.getId()
                            .longValue() == searchCriteria
                            .getTargetFolderId())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    logoUrl = getLogoUrl(personDetail.getPersonId(),
                            filteredFolderTos);
                } else {
                    logoUrl = getLogoUrl(personDetail.getPersonId(),
                            searchCriteriaForDivNetFolderTo.getNetworkFoldersData());
                }
                personDetail.setLogoUrl(logoUrl);
                newPersonDetails.add(personDetail);
            }
            searchResultData.setPersonDetails(newPersonDetails);
        }
        completableFuture.complete(searchResultData);
        return completableFuture;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        completableFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
        LOGGER.error(
                " ************** Error in proccessing searchPerson by criteria ************** " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info(TIME_DURATION+(end - start)+"ms");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where this *async* requirement comes from. Here you do what you need to do, get the request, fetch data from DB, and once you have it - respond immediately. There's nothing to be done in asynchronous manner. However, to me it sounds that your client is requesting to make an *async* call from UI, which is possibly **AJAX** or similar, which has nothing to do with this code. I would recommend removing all this *Future* logic.

Comment: Automation engineer is testing the api with 100 con current users which degrades the performance of the api.I used DefferredResult<> with @async before.It improved the performance by 50%.so I wanted to try CompletableFuture<>.

Comment: I wonder what performance it improved if you're not waiting & not getting the result

Comment: I was getting response there without using get

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to read more about *async* processing. [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) are usually a great start!

If you really want to get the result from a *Future* method, you need to wait for it.

There is a method [`public T get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) method in the `CompletableFuture` API to wait for wait for the result to be created and return the result once it's done.

If your job is to search a database for the result and then return it - you will still have to wait for it *async* is not much help in here. It would help you if you had to make multiple things at the same time, e.g. a call to DB, a web service and something else at the same time, then you can create an array of futures and wait for all of them to complete.

Or, let's say you're creating a `POST` method, so you can quickly validate the input and send to store to DB *async* while quickly returning the response to UI and *hoping* that your async method will be completed in another thread and not returning any errors to UI.

This is a great technique when you know what you're doing, but think if & when you really need it before using it.

The short way to "fix" this is:

```
CompletableFuture<ElasticSearchResultData> searchPerson = cubService.searchPersonAsync2(criteriaForDivNetFolderTo);
ElasticSearchResultData result = searchPerson.get();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
LOGGER.info("search Person "+mapper.writeValueAsString(result));
return result;
```

( and obviously change the method return signature )

Comment: I used DefferedResult<> as return type and used @async too in the service in another api implementation, it worked fine.Improved the performance too.I wonder why i didn't have to wait for results there and I was getting the response.

Comment: Used ElasticSearchResultData result = searchPerson.get() Still getting a blank response